# Link to Admin Dashboard in View

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I already have Active Admin all set up and now I was trying to add a link to the dashboard in my view.

I have the current_admin_user method in my application_controller:

```
def current_admin_user
  return nil if user_signed_in? && !current_user.admin?
  current_user
end
```

And my view is:

```
<% if current_admin_user %>
  <li><%= link_to "Admin", admin_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_admin_user'
```

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Why not put current_admin_user function into a helper instead?

Comment: I'm sorry but could you be more specific? I'm kind of new to rails.

Comment: I think this code is more appropriate to put in a helper instead, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the function in your `application_helpers.rb` file in the /helpers folder instead and it should work

```
  def current_admin_user
    return nil if user_signed_in? && !current_user.admin?
    current_user
  end
```

An alternative is to use **if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?** in your view

```
  <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Admin", admins_path %></li>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: undefined local variable or method `admin_path'

Comment: My guess it should say admins_path instead of singular admin_path. Updated my answer above.

Comment: I don't think a admins_path or admin_path exists. After I mapped the routes I tried 'admin_dashboard_path' and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use controller methods in views, you should add this line in your `application_controller`:

```
helper_method :current_admin_user
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% if current_admin_user? %>
<li><%= link_to "Admin", admin_path %></li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

If it fails try:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% if current_user.admin? %>
<li><%= link_to "Admin", admin_path %></li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Instead of two lines you can combine both if statements like my answer below.

Comment: True but if you were building a navigation list you could put links for signed in users between the two <% if ..%> tags and seperate user links from adminstrator links.